# How to install Django-1.11 in virtualenv?

Tags: python, 17.04, pip

When I do `pip install Django` in *virtualenv* after installing some dependencies it is showing an error message:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hhEPk0/Django/
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have both python version installed. Python 2.* and Python 3.*

Try

```
sudo pip3 install Django
```

or

```
sudo -H pip3 install Django
```